# Connection refused when i create a new Serveur in PostreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, server

When i try the add a new serveur to my PostgreSQL on the pc in my university, i get an error :

*could not connect to server : Connection refused the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checklist:

1. Is PostgreSQL installed (instructions dependent on OS)?
2. Is PostgreSQL running?  (on Windows, you start usually as a service.  On Linux, check via system or init scripts)
3. Is PostgreSQL set up to listen on sockets (on Windows this is automatic.  On Linux depends on your distro).
4. Is firewall software blocking the connection?